# Non Matching child elements also appear under XSL Templates

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="new_proto.xsl"?>
<Return>
 <SDSSJ type="form" />
 <JSFK type="form" />
 <KJFK type="form2" />
 <HJDHH type="form"> New Val </HJDHH>
 <NNDJB type="some"> 
    <DJSJJ type="form">
       THIS
    </DJSJJ>
    <KAKKK type="nope">
    DONT
    </KAKKK>
 Not
</NNDJB>
</Return>
```

I just want to get the name of all the nodes which have the attribute type='form' . So i tried the following XSL.

```
  1 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  2    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
  3       <xsl:template match="//*[@type='form']">
  4       <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
  5       </xsl:template>
  6 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

But instead of `SDSSJ JSFK HJDHH DJSJJ` , i get `SDSSJ JSFK HJDHH DJSJJ DONT Not` . Why are child elements which dont comply to the template appearing still ? What should i do to get rid of them ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this template:

```
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

Example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="//*[@type='form']">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

By default text is passed to the output. The above template will strip unmatched text.

Here's [what the spec says](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#built-in-rule) about the default XSLT template rules:

> There is a built-in template rule to allow recursive processing  to
>   continue in the absence of a successful pattern match by an  explicit
>   template rule in the stylesheet. This template rule  applies to both
>   element nodes and the root node. The following  shows the equivalent
>   of the built-in template rule:
>
> ```
> <xsl:template match="*|/">
>     <xsl:apply-templates/> 
> </xsl:template>
> ```
>
> There is also a built-in template rule for each mode, which  allows
>   recursive processing to continue in the same mode in  the absence of a
>   successful pattern match by an explicit  template rule in the
>   stylesheet. This template rule applies  to both element nodes and the
>   root node. The following  shows the equivalent of the built-in
>   template rule for mode m.
>
> ```
> <xsl:template match="*|/" mode="m">
>     <xsl:apply-templates mode="m"/> 
> </xsl:template>
> ```
>
> There is also a built-in template rule for text and  attribute nodes
>   that copies text through:
>
> ```
> <xsl:template match="text()|@*">
>     <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
> </xsl:template>
> ```
>
> The built-in template rule for processing instructions and  comments
>   is to do nothing.
>
> ```
> <xsl:template match="processing-instruction()|comment()"/>
> ```
>
> The built-in template rule for namespace nodes is also to  do nothing.
>   There is no pattern that can match a namespace  node; so, the built-in
>   template rule is the only template  rule that is applied for namespace
>   nodes.
>
> The built-in template rules are treated as if they were  imported
>   implicitly before the stylesheet and so have  lower import precedence
>   than all other template rules.  Thus, the author can override a
>   built-in template rule  by including an explicit template rule.

Comment: I am totally new to XSLT. Could you tel me where exactly should i add this ?

Comment: @Pradep - I added an example.

Comment: @Pradep - Also, you can remove the `//` from `//*[@type='form']`. You may also want to add a space after `xsl:value-of` (with `concat()` or `xsl:text`) if you need the values separated.

Comment: That worked ! But could you tell me how adding an extra template solved the problem ?

Comment: @Pradep - Basically that template overrode the default built-in template that is in XSLT. Please see my edit for more info on the default templates in XSLT.

Comment: Is there some way to write a template that doesn't always require overriding the default rule for text and attributes?  It seems I've managed to have them excluded sometimes when playing around with various different templates and match/select rules.

Comment: @Matt - You'd need to prevent everything else from being processed. So for what the OP was trying to do, you could add a template matching `/` and then do an `xsl:apply-templates` selecting `.//*[@type='form']`. That way only those elements would ever be processed.